# Allow username instead of e-mail in default Laravel 5.0 AuthController

Tags: authentication, laravel

Laravel 5.0 comes "out of the box" with an AuthController configured to handle user registrations and logins.

Is it possible to quickly and easily configure/modify this default configuration to use a more general "username" instead of an e-mail address?

Ideally, I'd like the users table to have a unique username instead of an e-mail address; but, I'd settle for just turning off the part of the validator that insists that the "E-mail Address" field on the login page be formatted like an e-mail address.

(I figured out how to turn off the client-side validation; but, I can't figure out how to turn off the server-side validation --- the part that generates the "Whoops: ... The email must be a valid email address." message.)

Answer (score 2):

The default validation rules are defined in `App\Services\Registrar`. Just remove the `email` rule from the `validator` method:

```php
public function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        //                   ^^^^^
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: lukasgeiter, I learned a LOT from you on StackOverflow last month from the moment I started to watch laravel questions/answers, thank you so much for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: @limonte You're welcome! Also you probably mean *"learned"* ;)